# Error when querying to a DbContext

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm working with EF CodeFirst. My classes are:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string ApellidoUno { get; set; }
    public string ApellidoDos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Telefono> Telefonos { get; set; }
}

public class Telefono
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Numero { get; set; }

    public virtual int IdPersona { get; set; }
    public virtual Persona Persona { get; set; }
}

public class ContactoContexto : DbContext
{
    public ContactoContexto()
        : base("EF_Model") 
    {  }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>().ToTable("Personas");

        // ... more Fluent API code..... 

        modelBuilder.Entity<Persona>()  
            .HasMany(x => x.Telefonos)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Persona)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdPersona);
    }

    public DbSet<Persona> Personas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Telefono> Telefonos { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try to select some data, I get the following error:

> Error  1   No se encontró una implementación del modelo de consulta para el tipo de origen 'EF_Model.ContactoContexto'. 'Where' no encontrado. c:\users\jmolina\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\prueba EF general\3. ModeloNEgocio\ModeloNegocio.cs  27  39  3. ModeloNegocio

My code to select is:

```
public class Intento
{
    public static IEnumerable<Persona> buscarcontactos(string nombre)
    {
        ContactoContexto conCon = new ContactoContexto();

        var personas = (from p in conCon where p.nombre == nombre select p);            
        return personas;
    }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Jeronimo

Comment: You could at least translate the exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're doing a Linq query in your context, you need to start from a `DbSet`. You should also instantiate the `DbContext` in a using statement to ensure that it gets properly disposed when you're done.

```
using (var conCon = new ContactoContexto())
{
    var personas = (from p in conCon.Personas where p.Nombre == nombre select p);

    // you need to use ToList() to actually materialize the result from the database
    return personas.ToList();
}
```